# Crypto Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

Tags: node.js, express, cryptojs

I am using crypto to store my password.. In my set Password controller, I am decrypting my password and saving it on the database .. its working fine.

```
var algorithm = "aes-192-cbc"; //algorithm to use
const passwordCrypto = "Hello darkness";
const key = crypto.scryptSync(passwordCrypto, 'salt', 24);
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    var encrypted = cipher.update(password, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex'); 

                    CustomerPasswordActivityLog.create({
                        mobile,
                        password : encrypted,
                        activity: 'abcd'
                    })
```

But when I am trying to decrypt from another controller It showing the following error.

```
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    var decrypted = decipher.update(passActivity.password, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8'); //deciphered text
```

here is the error

```
 Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
        at Decipheriv.final (internal/crypto/cipher.js:170:29)
        at /media/rabbani/_dde_data2/dpay_service/controller/authentication.js:590:85
        console.log(decrypted, "decrypt password");
```

Comment: please have a look on my question @AKX

Comment: I did have a look. Please add the `key` and `iv` bits for deciphering too. Also, you really should not be storing passwords in a way that you are able to decrypt them into plaintext at all.

Comment: I am using the same key and iv ( i have set it globally ). how can I sore password correctly on database ?

Comment: Cryptography is one of the hardest things in computer science – there's a 99% chance you'll get things wrong unless you're a professional cryptographer. And it just so happens that if you have a global key and IV, you're already doing things in an insecure way. If you read the manual for `createCipheriv`, it plainly tells you the IV must be unique for each message (password). You must also store the IV you use for each message, or you won't be able to decrypt them.

Comment: The current correct way to store a password is an one-way key derivation function and constant-time comparison, such as [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt).

Comment: What change do I need to execute the code successfully?

Comment: I am using crypto just for storing password history. so that I can give the user a similar password error message.. @AKX

Comment: If this is for a commercial/real-life project, please make sure it's okay that you're storing passwords in a reversible form. It most likely isn't okay, because it means that anyone who can access your database and knows the key/IV can then read everyone's passwords.